# Describe which partial orderings yield boolean algebras

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I thougt about propositional logic and boolean algebras and how propositional logic is (at least from one point of view) not really about $\land,\lor,\neg,...$ but about boolean operators, i.e. n-ary functions which map $0$-$1$-sequences of length $n$ into $\{0,1\}$, and how to use a finite subset of those (base) to encode all of them.

With boolean algebras it's a little bit similar, one way to think of them is as a mathematical structure associated with a set $X\supseteq\{0,1\}$ which enlarges each boolean operator $f$ to an $X$-valued operator ${\cal X}(f)$ such that this operation is compatible with function composition, i.e. $${\cal X}(f)({\cal X}(g_1),\dots,{\cal X}(g_n))={\cal X}(f(g_1,\dots,g_n)).$$  But any boolean algebra is also a lattice (via $\land$ and $\lor$) and any lattice structure can be described as partial order.  I just wonder if it's also possible to describe the partial order on a boolean algebra in terms which do not prioritize the operations $\land$ and $\lor$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A poset is the underlying poset of a [Heyting algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra) iff as a category, it has finite products, finite coproducts, and is [cartesian closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category). Every Boolean algebra is a Heyting algebra, so these are necessary conditions for a poset to be the underlying poset of a Boolean algebra. Heyting algebras are to [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) as Boolean algebras are to propositional logic; see, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/how-to-invent-intuitionistic-logic/).

The remaining question is which Heyting algebras are Boolean algebras. In every Heyting algebra we can define a negation operator

$$\neg x = (x \Rightarrow \bot)$$

where $\Rightarrow$ denotes implication / exponential and $\bot$ denotes false / the initial object. There is a natural map $x \to \neg \neg x$, and a Heyting algebra is a Boolean algebra iff this natural map is always an isomorphism, or in other words, iff [double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) holds.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the link to your blog post, this was exactly the question I set out to answer (how to invent intuitionistic logic), the thing with boolean algebra was just something I came across.  So that is really helpful :)